# Using MySQL and MSSQL selection flexibility in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, migrate

I am working on a web application(using PHP) which will use MySQL database in initial stage & once it gets ready, I will use same application to connect Remote MSSQL database & not the MySQL database. Any suggestion which standards I will have to keep in mind before developing this application so that it remaining flexible & I will just have to make few configuration changes in application when transferred from MySQL to MSSQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [php PDO extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php). Using this you should be able to easily transfer your code to use the new database by just changing your connection parameters.